# Template function with an arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding

I'd like to write a function `invoke_measure_time` that will measure execution time of any other function given as an argument. I partially solved my problem, I have the following piece of code:

```
int sum(int a, int b){
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    return a + b;
}

template<typename T>
std::pair<std::chrono::milliseconds, T> invoke_measure_time(std::function<T()> f){
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto f_result = f();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);

    return std::make_pair(duration, f_result);
}

int main(){
    auto fun = std::bind(sum, 10, 20);
    auto emma = invoke_measure_time<int>(fun);
    std::cout << "time: " << emma.first.count() << ", result = " << emma.second << std::endl;
}
```

It works fine, results are as expected, but the first line of `main` gives me a headache. How can I modify `invoke_measure_time` to accept any function, not only these with no arguments? I'd love my main to look like:

```
int main(){
    auto emma = invoke_measure_time<int, int, int>(sum, 10, 20);
    std::cout << "time: " << emma.first.count() << ", result = " << emma.second << std::endl;
}
```

or something like that. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution is to make `invoke_measure_time` take any function object that can be called without parameters (i leave out the timing stuff for the sake of brevity):

```
template <typename F>
auto invoke_and_measure(F f) -> decltype(f()) {
    return f();
}
```

And then any funtion, with arbitrary parameters, for example your `sum`:

```
int sum(int a,int b) { return a+b; }
```

can be wrapped into a lambda that can be called without parameters:

```
int main() {
    auto x = invoke_and_measure([](){ return sum(1,2);});
    std::cout << x;
}
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/04MlA7uZz2RhOrnI)

Note that lambdas are usually easier to work with than `bind`. There are some corner cases that `bind` can do but not a lambda, but actually I dont know any from the top of my head ;)

Comment: Your solution is great and you should feel great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

If you instead change the temaplte type to just be a generic type then we can add a variadic template parameter to take the arguments for the function.

```
template<typename Function, typename... Args>
auto invoke_measure_time(Function f, Args&&... args) {
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto f_result = f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);

    return std::make_pair(duration, f_result);
}
```

Takes any function like type and forwards the arguments you pass to `invoke_measure_time` to it.  It also has the added benifit of being able to call it like

```
int main(){
    auto emma = invoke_measure_time(sum, 10, 20);
    std::cout << "time: " << emma.first.count() << ", result = " << emma.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is indeed exactly what I asked for, but I accepted a different one as it's much cleaner than approach I proposed. Great solution though!

Answer (score 2):

You might do the following:

```
template<typename F, typename ... Ts>
auto invoke_measure_time(F&& f, Ts&&... args)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto f_result = std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);

    return std::make_pair(duration, f_result);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ed160adab7d99f4)

Case when `f` return `void` is problematic Btw.